# Are there performance reasons against goto?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, c, ipad

GOTO, does it affect the performance while it is executed and run on the device?

Is it a good practice to use GOTO in objective C or is it bad practice to use it?

And, when is it a good choice to use GOTO statement?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, if you do `label: goto label;` then it **does affect** performance. Otherwise I don't see the relation.

Comment: even break is considered as bad practice in some cases but if you have to write a lot t od othe same thing without goto you can use it without any performance issues

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `goto` is simply a jump, so that its effect on performance is practically zero. It’s a bad practice because it harms code readability; you can mostly do without it. Some of the cases where it makes sense to use `goto` are described in previous questions, just [search for goto](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=goto).

Answer (score 3):

Using a go to statement is usually a bad practice, especially in a object oriented language(where you can achieve the same purpose in an OO way easyly ), but not from a performance point of view but rather from the code readability point of view...

Comment: It's not related to OO. It's related to the fact whether or not a programming language has loops.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in BAD and GOOD practice this is up to your requirement.
If you have same code which you want to execute you can say loop then you can use `goto`. Well here is a small example about this I think it would clear your doubt.

Declare any `label` name, here `hello` is `label` then you can call it using `goto` statement like this -

```
hello:
    NSLog(@"Print hello!");
    goto hello;
```

This would print 'Print hello!' again and again.

Comment: I know the usage, just wanted to know the side effect of the usage of GOTO. Thanks.

Comment: There is no side effect of any code. When you use wrong statement or wrong code at wrong place then it seems to be `Side Effects` :)

Comment: Well, generally we dont use `goto` in Objective-C because we can use methods which is much better than `goto`.

Answer (score 1):

Not affecting the performance, just for a good structure and readability which are important features of professional programming. But sometimes, using goto may help to ease complexity in cases where the loop is too deep, but you want to jump out when certain condition is triggered. Even so, it can also be avoided in other ways.

Answer (score 1):

In principle `goto` *can* affect performance simply by being present in the function.

The performance difference will almost always be unnoticeable, and there are a lot of things other than `goto` than can slightly perturb the optimizer and affect performance. But if you're interested you could examine the emitted code for differences.

It's a basic requirement in the emitted code that the same registers must be used for the same things at the source and target of the goto[*]. This constrains the register allocation when the compiler optimizes the code. Such constraints may have no effect at all, they may slow things down or cause additional code to be emitted. If they speed things up, it can only be by accident because the compiler's heuristics were in effect incorrect when applied to the unconstrained version.

The effect might be more pronounced for a computed goto (a GNU extension), where you can store a label in a variable and goto the variable. In that case, every possible target has to share a register state with every possible source.

What *doesn't* (normally) make a difference to performance is `goto` the start or end of a block vs. the equivalent `break` or `continue` or `else`. It's all the same to the optimizer: the compiler breaks your code down into so-called "basic blocks" with jumps and conditional jumps between them. It doesn't normally care whether the reason for the jump is a `goto` or not, and it has to get the register states right no matter which. This is why almost any programming construct can be described as "goto in disguise" by someone who's only thinking about the emitted instructions.

[*] to be more precise -- there could be an implicit zap at a goto, meaning that some register is used for one thing at the source and isn't used at all at the target. But you can't have some register that the target expects to contain a particular value (like the current value of a variable) and the source doesn't. So if that was the case before and then you add the goto, either the target needs to stop expecting it, or the source needs to put it there. Typically either one is going to require extra code to shuffle values between registers and stack.